# Jquery infinitescroll seems to not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

On this [page](http://rubyfish.devel.hatimeria.com/search) I'm trying to use plugin "Jquery infinitescroll". I attached js plugin file into my page and add this

```
  $('#listView').infinitescroll({
            itemSelector: '.property'          
    });
```

but nothing change. I'm new in js so I will be very grateful for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this plugin but I found some useful information that might help you out:

[jQuery scroll show hidden content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036610/jquery-scroll-show-hidden-content)

Comment: I checked this one. But as i said I'm not good in js and I need it to be responsive. In first Fiddle samples only first line of containers is loading - but I don't know how many will fit to screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular JS

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/)

```
function Main($scope) {
$scope.items = [];

var counter = 0;
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({id: counter});
        counter += 10;
    }
};

$scope.loadMore();}
angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];

    elm.bind('scroll', function() {
        if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
            scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I need this page to be responsive so I can't use fixed height.

Comment: Can u use this -> jscroll.com.
U can download it from here --> https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll.

Comment: I put it into code but strange things appear. My content is now doubled.