# Infinite pagination or scroll down-displaying li elements

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement infinite scroll down option in my web page.I am using Java and dropwizard in my project.Using mustache,generated li tags.

ul tag looks like below format.
I need to display first 8 elements and then while scrolling, it should display the remaining.I have tried many examples,but didn't get desired output.

```
<ul class="clearfix" id="myList">
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
<li>element</li>
</ul>
```

If anyone knows,please help me to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show only next 10 divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843381/show-only-next-10-divs)

Comment: Got output by referring this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10036744/5819582